# Remotehost closes connection on LDAPS

Tags: python, ssl, ldap

I try to figure out where my problem with an LDAPS connection is.

I can authenticate a user with LDAP but not with LDAPS.

No Matter what I try, I get: `ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: socket ssl wrapping error: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

What I found out:
On LDAP the Host was listening, on LDAPS not.
On LDAP the Socket was open, on LDAPS not.

That's my code at the Moment:

```
import os
import socket
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\ldap3-2.9.1\\')
import pyasn1
import ssl
import time

from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SAFE_SYNC, Tls, NTLM, SUBTREE, LEVEL, ALL

aduser = 'aduser'
adpassword = 'adpassword'

t = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE)
server = Server(host='IP', port=636, use_ssl = True, tls=t, get_info='ALL')

con = Connection(server, user=aduser, password=adpassword, client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC ,auto_bind='NONE', version=3, authentication='SIMPLE', raise_exceptions=True)

print("LDAP Protocol Version: ",con.version)
print("Result: ",con.result)
print("Server: ",con.server)
print("Read Only?: ",con.read_only)
print("Listening?: ",con.listening)
print("Socket not Open ? : ",con.closed)
print("Open SSL Version : ",ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

con.bind()

print(con)
```

If somebody can show me another way for a LDAPS user authentication I would try that too.

Is it possible that this is a Host problem?

Comment: *"On LDAP the Host was listening , on LDAPS not"* - That sounds like a server problem. You can't connect to LDAPS if the server is not setup for LDAPS.

Comment: i had to deliver the cipher ... that was the missing part. Problem solved!

Comment: If you solved your problem in a way that can help others, please consider posting an answer